# PHP How to implement multiple web services simultaniously?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on an energy project. In my site there are may energy services are registered with there enrollment process through web services. Initially it was 1 to begin with now 3 more came to integrate.

On the very first page I've to show the plans based on the zip codes. Now on this page I've to request to all 4 energy provider to list the energy plans.

To request each service at a time in sequential way definitely it will take more time as I've to get the data from external source and this is the first page so I do not want to make it slow down at the first instance only.

How can I make request to all the services simultaneously and collect the data from each services and list it on the final page.

Comment: I know many will complain, but have you thought about multi-threading? From the first few google results, these look like good places to start... http://villavu.com/forum/showthread.php?t=73623 and http://blog.motane.lu/2009/01/02/multithreading-in-php/ support looks slim, but this might speed up things by having all 4 request going at "once" — thats what I imagine at least...

Comment: What about caching? How often do these plans change? Does it have to be real-time?  Why not have a cron job that polls all the services every 1-5 minutes and stores the results in memcache or a MySQL HEAP table?  Then your front-end could read from the cache instead of the webservices.

Comment: @Costa Sounds to be good solution. But the problem is even I don't know how many zipcodes are and how often they changes the plan. There could be around 50K zipcodes. But I'll keep this in mind and implement where it will be feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really only one non-nasty way to do this with PHP when executing on a web server. You will need the cURL module compiled into PHP. It has built-in support for executing parallel requests. Look at the comments and documentation on [www.php.net](http://www.php.net/) for usage examples.

Try: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Other options, like forking background processes or calling a UNIX shell, are terrible to maintain and rarely cross-platform. Multithreading isn't a valid option in nearly any common PHP environment.

I should mention, although not necessarily suggest, that an AJAX approach could be used. It's not as lightweight in all cases, but it should be weighed.

Comment: When dealing with a similar situation i solved it by offloading the work to get data back in a cake shell, which used pcntl_fork to run simultaneous webservice requests. The child processes stored the responses in shared memory, and when all processes were done, the parent shell process collects them and sends it back to the webrequest. It worked for me to decrease load times by large numbers. But take into account what Pestilence said about this solution.

Comment: @pestilence What if I am using different different request for calling webservices. one using REST secong using SOAP third using Curl.. At that time How it will help ful.. thank